# How to control multiple modal boxes on one webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently rebuilding my portfolio and have cards for each of the projects that I've worked on, the idea being that when the user clicks on a card it opens a modal box containing more information about the project and a link to it.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to have multiple modal boxes on the same page, without writing a new block of code for every single box. I'm guessing I'll need some sort of for loop but I've been experimenting all day and can't find anything that works.

This is the JavaScript I have so far:

```js
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("modal")[1];
var card = document.getElementsByClassName("card")[1];

// When the user clicks on the card, open the modal box
card.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal box, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
```

Many thanks!

Comment: A way to achieve this is having a Modal div working as a container. Then each "card info" can be added separately on divs with different id's. When clicking on a card, with like a data-id pointing at the id, you can show the modal with that specific id.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class in your modal something like `.modal`;

```js
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
      event.target.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: Already done, each modal box shares the same class but the JavaScript only targets the first instance of that class so only the first modal box will open